# How to automatically rotate credentials of service accounts on Red Hat IDM

Tags: rotation, redhat, credentials

I've been searching the documentation on - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/linux_domain_identity_authentication_and_policy_guide/pwd-policies-how - to figure out how to automate password rotation on service accounts. Unfortunately, I cannot find any available option on Red Hat documentation. I've found some 3rd-party applications that can automate the rotation of the service accounts' passwords. I'll like to find out if the 3rd-party application is the only option here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, Max lifetime of service account passwords on redhat IDM = 90 days. No configuration needed to automate the process, except you require a lower Max lifetime.